# AngularFire change reference in factory when routeParameter changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am currently working on an angular app with firebase (using angularFire) with a lot of factories providing firebase arrays and objects.

I need to change the references of all factorys multiple times in a session whenever the route parameter "element_id" changes but angularjs loads all the factories once they are first called and I don't see a way to update the reference after this initial call.

I've tried reloading the app using

```
$route.reload();
```

which changed nothing and

```
$window.location.reload();
```

which either caused error 404 because this page is not available in html5 mode localhost:8000/element1 is not existing or took me back to localhost:8000 without my element_id when I wasn't using html5 mode.

Here's one of my factories with my root firebase factory:

```
app.factory("fireroot", function(){
  var reference = new Firebase("https://mybase.firebaseio.com");
  return reference;
});

app.factory('core_data', function($firebaseObject, fireroot, $routeParams) {
  var reference = fireroot.child("elements").child($routeParams.element_id).child("core-data");
  var core_data = $firebaseObject(reference);

  return core_data;
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help, I only made my past years of coding thanks to this community, finally it's time to actively participate :).

Comment: Factories are **singletons**. If you want something such as `core_data` to change when the route changes, you should put it in a resolver function of your route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great time to start participating!

Don't inject `$routeParams` in a factory. Use that inside of a controller, or better yet, the **router**.

Try returning a function from the `core_data` factory that can construct a `$firebaseObject` based on an id.

Then in the resolve object in the route, you can access the `$routeParams` and construct a `$firebaseObject`. Then you can return the `$loaded()` promise, so Angular will load the view when the promise is resolved.

Now your controller is super thin because the config did the hard part for you.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'firebase'])
   .factory('coreData', CoreDataFactory)
   .controller('MyCtrl', MyController)
   .config(ApplicationConfig);

function CoreDataFactory($firebaseObject, fireroot) {
  return function(id) {
    var ref = fireroot.child("elements").child(id).child("core-data");
    return $firebaseObject(ref);
  }
}

function ApplicationConfig($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/path/:element_id', {
    controller: 'MyCtrl as ctrl',
    view: 'view.html',
    resolve: {
      data: function(coreData, $route) {
         return coreData($route.current.params.element_id).$loaded();
      }
    }
  });
}

function MyController(data) {
  this.coreData = data;
}
```

[And incase you are wondering, the format comes from the Angular Styleguide.](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)

Comment: Note that the `$routeParams` are only updated after a route change completes successfully. This means that you cannot rely on `$routeParams` being correct in route resolve functions. Instead you can use `$route.current.params` to access the new route's parameters. -- [AngularJS $routeParams API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams).

Comment: Also you need the parameter in the route. Something like `.when('/somepath/:element_id'`

Comment: Great, thanks, that looks elegant! I'm still trying to figure out where `data` comes from in `function MyController(data) {}` and how I can distribute the results from the coreData factory to multiple controllers. Is there a solution or should I call the factory with the `$routeParams` in every controller that needs these data? Also, does this approach work with more than one factory as well?